# React Native go back on button click

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm quite new to react native development. I'm trying to handle some basic authentication. The main page (App.js) first check's if it can find any Asyncstorage parameters in my case a **access_token**. If it cant find any it'll redirect to the login page, else it would take you to the dashboard.

My problem is that after user clicks login in **LOGIN.JS** (data sent to server and token is received )the token is then saved at an Asyncstorage key, after this it should take you back to (App.js) but it doesn't.

NOTE :  I did not include the full render code eg: TextInput

## APP.JS

```
import Login from './src/compoments/login/Login'
import Dashboard from './src/compoments/dashboard/Dashboard'
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isTokenValid: false,
      access_token: '',

    }
  }


  render() {
    console.disableYellowBox = true;



    this.loadToken();
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isTokenValid;
    console.log("Logged IN : ", isLoggedIn);

    if (isLoggedIn) 
      return <Dashboard     />;
    else 
      return <Login 
          onLoginPress={() => this.setState({isLoggedIn: true})}
        />;




  }

  loadToken(){

    retrieveData = async () => {
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token');
        console.log("TOKEN", value);
        if (value !== null) {
          this.setState({access_token : value});
          this.setState({isTokenValid : true});
          console.log(value);
        }else{

          this.setState({isTokenValid : false});

        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("ERROR : ", error)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

## LOGIN.JS

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          username: '',
          password: '',
          param3: '',
          serverResponse:'',
          isLoggingIn: false,
          isLoggedIn: false
        }
      }

 render() {
return (



  <View style={styles.container}>


                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} 
                                        onPress={this.getLoginApi.bind(this)}>
                                <Text  style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>


                    </TouchableOpacity> 


            {this.state.isLoggingIn && <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />}


  </View>



);


getLoginApi(){

  this.setState({ isLoggingIn: true, message: '' });


    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('param1', this.state.username);
    formData.append('param2', this.state.password);
    formData.append('param3', this.state.param3); 

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
      if (request.readyState !== 4) {
        return;
      }

      if (request.status === 200) {

        this.setState({ isLoggingIn: false })
        const status = this.getJSONValue(request.responseText,"status");
        console.log('SERVER RESPONSE : ',  status);
        if(status=="success"){

            const token = this.getJSONValue(request.responseText,"token");
            console.log("ACCESS TOKEN : ", token);
            AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', token);
            this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
            this.props.onLoginPress();   
        }



      } else {
        this.setState({ isLoggingIn: false })
        console.warn('error');
      }
    };

    request.open('POST', 'https://bla.com/test.php');
    request.send(formData);


}



 getJSONValue(jsonObj, findKey){

   let response = '';

    JSON.parse(jsonObj, (key, value) => {

        if(key==findKey){

           response = value;

        }

      });  
      return response;
}
```

}

Comment: What navigation do you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code did not work because inside render App.js, you use state isTokenValid to check which component to render.

```js
 const isLoggedIn = this.state.isTokenValid;
```

But when you send the props to Login.js

```js
<Login 
  onLoginPress={() => this.setState({isLoggedIn: true})}
/>
```

you send the props onLoginPress but you set state isLoggedIn to true.. thus, it create a new state named isLoggedIn. it did not change the value of your const to true because state and const is different.

just change to this and it should work

```js
<Login 
      onLoginPress={() => this.setState({isTokenValid: true})}
    />
```